# Intro video using <video> tag

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am trying to create an introduction video for a website without using flash. It should pop up when the page is loaded and there should be an option to skip it. Is this possible just using html5?

I cannot find anything about this. I just find things on how to create a video or the video tag in general.

I am really new to this and would be very happy for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<video src="intro.mp4"></video>
<a href="page2.html">Skip</a>
```

Comment: Was this helpful? I tried to give the simplest possible answer. If there are additional requirements (like automatically skipping to the second page if the video plays all the way through), you can probably get help with that too.